# How can I use a float as an argument in LLDB?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, gdb, lldb

I'm debugging a `UIProgressView`. Specifically I'm calling `-setProgress:` and `-setProgress:animated:`.

When I call it in LLDB using:

```
p (void) [_progressView setProgress:(float)0.5f]
```

the progressView ends up with a progress value of 0. Apparently, LLDB doesn't parse the float value correctly.

Any idea how I can get float arguments being parsed correctly by LLDB?

Btw, I'm experiencing the same problem in GDB.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. `p (void) [_progressView setProgress:(float)0.5f]` followed by `p (float)[_progressView progress]` in the debugger prints the value 0.5.

Comment: you will have to wait for the next rendering cycle to complete until you can see the updated progress on screen!

Comment: and another idea: is _progressView nil? you can message nil and it would explain the return value of 0

Comment: Martin R: strange, I get 0 when doing this.

Comment: Martin Ulrich: Of course, I know that I've to continue to see anything on screen. It's actually changed to 0 (from another value) which proves it's not nil.

Comment: So `p (float)[_progressView progress]` prints a nonzero value in the debugger before you try to set the value to 0.5?

Comment: Martin R: Yes: `p (float) [_progressView progress]` prints `(float) $0 = 0.78`.

Comment: What happens if you just try `p (void)[p setProgress:0.5]` ?

Comment: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'p'`. Or what do you mean with `p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode 4.5 and before, this was a common problem.  If I remember correctly, what was really happening there was that the old C no-prototype type promotion rules were in effect.  If you were passing a floating point value, it had type double.  If you were passing an integral value, it was passed as int, that kind of thing.  If you wrote (float)0.8f, lldb would take those 4 bytes of (float) and pass them to something that reads 8 bytes and interprets it as a double.

In Xcode 4.6, lldb will fetch the argument types from the Objective-C runtime, if it can, so it knows that the argument is really taking a float here.  You shouldn't even need the (float) cast.

My guess is that when you give lldb a pointer to an object `p (void) [0x260da630 setProgress:...`, the expression parser isn't looking at the object's isa to get the class & getting the types out of it.  As soon as you added a cast to the object address, it got the types.

I *think* when you wrote `setProgress:(float)0.8f` for gdb, it would take this as a special indication that this argument is a float type -- in essence, you were providing the prototype.  It's something that I think lldb's expression parser should do some time in the future, but the fact that clang is used to do all the expression parsing means that it's a little harder to shoehorn these non-standard meanings into it.  (there are already a few, of course, e.g. `p $r0` works ;)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Regarding GDB, I tested it as well and it behaved exactly like LLDB here. So the `(float)0.5f` cast didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. In reality my LLDB command looked slightly different:

```
p (void) [0x260da630 setProgress:(float)0.8f animated:NO]
```

where `0x260da630` is my UIProgressView. Apparently, the debugger really needs to know the exact type of the receiving object and doesn't honor the cast of the argument, so

```
p (void) [(UIProgressView*)0x260da630 setProgress:(float)0.8f animated:NO]
```

works. (Even casting to `id` wasn't sufficient!)

Thanks for your comments, Martin R and Martin Ullrich, and apologies for having broken my question for better readability!

Btw, I swear, I had used the property instead of the address as well. But perhaps restarting Xcode also helped…